# Reading from STDIN in Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

So I wrote code which would read something from STDIN. It works. But when I write something, a `string`, a `number`, and press ENTER it throws an error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. The code looks like this:

```
SYSCALL32 = 0x80
EXIT = 1
STDIN = 0
READ = 3
STDOUT = 1
WRITE = 4
B_SIZE = 80
.data
    BUF: .space B_SIZE
.text
.globl _start
_start:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl $READ, %eax
    movl $STDIN, %ebx
    movl $BUF, %ecx
    movl $B_SIZE, %edx
    int $SYSCALL32
```

I compile it with a `Makefile`:

```
# linking
main: main.o #
    ld -o main main.o
# compiling
main.o: main.s #
    as -o main.o main.s
```

Im running this on Manjaro 64 bit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have no ending to your program so execution continues into uninitialized memory and crashes. PS: also it's a bad idea to use 32 bit syscalls in 64 bit mode.

Comment: So I should put `$EXIT` to `%eax` and `SYSCALL32` again, right? Hmm, and those 32 bit syscalls, should I then use `syscall` (don't values like EXIT, READ change then?)

Comment: Yes, yes and yes :)

Comment: As a workaround for this early examples, you can also compile it for 32b target (fix 64b regs usage of course). But if you want to work in 64b, then "yes, yes and yes" :)